# why getTarget() doesn't give me the value set by setTarget()

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I want to set a target and then console it by getTarget, the problem is when I create a new arc rotate camera with target new BABYLON.Vector3.(0,1,1) and then I want to get this target by getTarget() it consoles the old one !

```
  camera1 =  new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera("Camera",0, 0, 10, new 
  BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(), scene);
  scene.activeCamera=camera1;
  camera1.attachControl(canvas,false);
  var vv=new BABYLON.Vector3(0,1,1);
  camera1.setTarget(vv);
  console.log(camera1.getTarget());
```

any idea

Thanks

Anes